# Not able to connect Wifi

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, broadcom

I know that this problem occurred many times, but still I could not fix this for me. I installed `Ubuntu 14.04.3 32bit` version on my `Lenovo Thinkpad S10e`.

At first it was not able to connect to any `Wifi`, since it could not detect it. After updating, the **Wifi was detected but it would not accept the right password**. The password is correct, the internet is working fine on other devices. I installed WinXP before, the wifi connection worked beautifully. No matter if I installed Linux Mint, Lubuntu or Ubuntu, the wifi problem was the same.

The thing that could be interesting: `14e4:1713 (rev02) Broadcom` (Whatever that is). 
I am a complete newbie, so please excuse if some necessary information are missing here.

EDIT:
`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Lenovo IdeaPad S10e [17aa:3a23]
Kernel driver in use: tg3 
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]  
Kernel driver in use: wl
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: just updated, i hope that helps. thank you for your fast reply

Comment: Please add output of `rfkill list`

Comment: Okay, I tried to fix it with different other forum pages. What I get by entering `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`is:

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation Netlink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)

Subsytem: Lenovo Ideapad S10e [17aa:3a23]

Kernel driver in use: tg3

05:00.0 Network controller [0280]:Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11g/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)

Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]

Kernel driver in use: wl

Comment: Shall I reinstall?
By typing `rfkill list`I get:
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN Soft blocked: no, Hard blocked: no 1: Ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth soft blocked no hard blocked no, 2: hci: Bluetooth, 3: phy0: Wireless LAN, 4: brcwl-0: Wireless LAN; **all entries are neither soft nor hard blocked**

Comment: Look at the answer again. `wl` is a wrong driver for this adapter.

Comment: Well, back to the other driver: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2' :shows me dirver in use: b43-pci-bridge; And it still does not connect.

Comment: `rfkill list` stays the same. Any other ideas which driver could work properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong wireless driver installed. Connect to the internet by wire and run in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer
```

and reboot.

Comment: I tried it. Did not work :( It still tells me that network authentification is required. Do you have another idea?

Comment: There is no other solution. What does `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` show now?

Comment: Now it is:

02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM5906M Fast Ethernet PCI Express [14e4:1713] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Lenovo IdeaPad S10e [17aa:3a23]
Kernel driver in use: tg3 
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4312 802.11b/g LP-PHY [14e4:4315] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Broadcom Corporation Device [14e4:04b5]  
Kernel driver in use: b43-pci-bridge

Comment: Did the firmware install without errors? were you connected by wire?

Comment: Can the password be typed into terminal and be displayed correctly?

Comment: Firmware installed without any errors. I did installed linux mint once, ubuntu twice, lubuntu once and after that i installed ubuntu again. alwaays the same problem. and i was connected by wire during the whole process.
Yes, the password is shown correctly in the dialog box.
Thank you again for your reply!